# how to get Multiple tuples from where Clause in sqlite database

Tags: mysql, sql, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader

if i have a table

```
song_name| song_Url | artist | year
```

and i have an array of string contains name of the songs 
and through name of songs i want to get `song_url, artist , year` in one query

like  `select song_Url,artist,year from tbl_music where song_name="aaa","bbb"`

my problem is that i want to get columns  `song_url, artist , year`  based on the names of the songs  in one query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT song_Url, artist, year FROM TableName WHERE song_name IN ("aaa", "bbb");
```

Or:

```
SELECT song_Url, artist, year FROM TableName WHERE song_name = "aaa" OR song_name =  "bbb";
```

Comment: thank you but i,m getting song_Url, artist, year of aaa  not both

Comment: i want the details(song_Url,artist, year )of both song_name

Comment: @user3700517 Check your `song_name` column data. Above query will list out both 'aaa' and 'bbb'

Comment: yes ! i have check it only given me the song_url,artist,year of the song aaa only

Comment: Do you have record song_name started with `bbb `

Comment: Thank you so much i had made some silly mistake and i have put some space after the song name in my database table it,s perfectly working

Comment: @user3700517 Okay..glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

You should try the IN query since you want to pass on multiple values

```
SELECT song_Url, artist, year FROM table WHERE song_name IN ("aaa", "bbb");
```